# Could not load type of field Plugin Fingerprin

Tags: c#, maui

I try to authenticate with  Plugin Fingerprin   **Using .NET MAUI**

I have the following code

```
private async void OnBiometricClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var request = new AuthenticationRequestConfiguration("Validate that you have fingers", "Because without them you will not be able to access");
    var result = await fingerprint.AuthenticateAsync(request);
    if (result.Authenticated)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Authenticate!", "Access Granted", "OK");
    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Unauthenticated", "Access Denied", "OK");
    }
}
```

In this line the following error is thrown

```
var result = await fingerprint.AuthenticateAsync(request);
```

This is the error

> System.TypeLoadException Mensaje = Could not load type of field
> 'Plugin.Fingerprint.FingerprintImplementation+d__5:<>u__2'
> (11) due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000035 from typeref
> (expected class 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter' in
> assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e') assembly:mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
> type:System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter member:(null)

I can't figure out why this is happening if I have the nugets installed and the code is fine
Could the phone not have permissions to access the fingerprint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue on my side. To fix the issue, please follow the solution below:

1. In the **MAUI .NET** project, install the [Plugin.Fingerprint NuGet](https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint) package. You will need version `3.0.0-beta.1`, which is currently in preview, so remember to check Include Preview.
2. Since version 2, the plugin uses Android X. Therefore, [Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration) must be installed in your Android project.
3. You must add the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

4. In the `MauiProgram.cs` file, you need add the following lines:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(IFingerprint), CrossFingerprint.Current);
```

5. For **iOS**, you just have to add the `NSFaceIDUsageDescription` to the `Info.plist` file to describe the reason why our application will use Face ID (see Documentation). Otherwise, the app will crash when you initiate a Face ID authentication on iOS 11.3+.

```
<key>NSFaceIDUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need your face to unlock magic things</string>
```

Comment: @ Alexandar mayo the answer is correct I spent two days with this error and the problem was the version of the plugin thank you very much dear